# Why does my “Review (voting) Queues” red indicator light keep coming on in error?

Tags: bug, voting

It shows up as red, which one time out of ten truthfully means there is a vote to be made.  Fine. But the other 90% of the time there are no votes pending. Is this because I have a lower than 1000 rep?

Is this happening to anyone else? If so, it would seem likely to be a glitch, so who would I report it to?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, it's exceptional if there's no red indicator. I thought there had been a Meta post about this, but I can't find it.

Comment: @Joachim, do you know whom we might contact? Your corroboration leads me to believe this is a bug...

Comment: This is definitely a StackExchange behavior rather than A&C specific, and there are a number of posts on meta about it ([search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=review%20queue%20red%20dot)). In a nutshell, I think it has something to do with items in the review queue needing attention even if you don't actually have the rep to deal with it (I've seen it happen on other sites when there are tag edits pending when I didn't have the necessary rep to review, for example).

Comment: And I just approved about 10 tag edits -- can you check the review queue icon now and see if it still has a red dot? :)

Comment: @Erica, The dot is gone at this time...  I haven’t been on here for a few hours, but I will keep you posted if the behavior continues..  I’m working on my rep so some of the flags were likely mine.. :)

Comment: Anndddd, woops it’s back...

Comment: So, @Erica, you think it might have something to do with there being queues in general? In that case, it seems it's buggy behaviour that would have been ironed out long ago, were it not for the relatively low traffic on A&C.

Comment: The [bug] tag should technically report it to the proper ticket queue for SE. But AFAIK, the indicators on the queues have difficulties being real-time representations of status because of caching, how often the script that checks is run, and other technical problems. It may be worthwhile to raise this on main Meta.SE, but it may be a duplicate (which would still get us the answer we need)

Comment: I have posted this question with the “bug” tag over in Meta Stack Exchange at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338688/red-indicator-light-falsely-positive-most-of-the-time. Reviewing duplicate questions, I did not see anything answered within the past nearly 2 years.

Comment: [Likely related](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331/experiment-more-aggressive-review-queue-indicator).

Answer (score 1):

## **AN UPDATE AND A CALL TO (a sort of strange) ACTION:**

I posted this question [in Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338688/red-indicator-light-falsely-positive-most-of-the-time) this morning. The following comment provides a status update and an odd call to action:

> [The "Q&A": "How does the review-needed indicator light work exactly?”
>   (dated 10-18-17)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302226/how-does-the-review-needed-indicator-work-exactly/302608#302608) is an announcement, complaints rather than answers,
>   go beneath it. Makyen's complaint addresses your concern. Upvoting
>   that 'answer' is one way to bring attention to the issue, indeed
>   there's a discussion that it's tricky to set the threshold properly -
>   what's needed is a smarter algorithm. Even the grey dot lies. – Rob

So what Rob is telling us is, **we all need to upvote that particular answer of Makyen’s as one way to bring attention to the issue.**  I am not extremely convinced it will work, but there is the link, if you would please go there and up vote his answer...  It is the third of four answers, you will need to scroll down a ways.

Is this really how things work on here when something needs to be fixed???  Isn’t that a bit ironical considering this entire entity was invented by coders???

Thanks all.

Comment: Done. Thanks for looking into it. And yes, it is, but "priorities", I assume.